# Why synchronized keyword does not create monitor enter every time

Tags: java

Why synchronized keyword does not create monitor enter  at byte code level  every time  I use it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `synchronized` keyword can be used in two ways:

1. When you use `synchronized(obj)` inside the body of a function, the compiler will emit `monitorenter`/`monitorexit` bytecodes for the relevant monitor.
2. If the entire method is declared `synchronized`, in the bytecodes the method will be marked as `ACC_SYNCHRONIZED`. The JVM will implicitly enter and exit the monitor when entering/exiting the method. No `monitorenter`/`monitorexit` bytecodes are emitted, nor indeed required.

Consider the following two methods:

```
public class Sync {

    public void f() {
        synchronized (this) {
        }
    }

    public synchronized void g() {
    }

}
```

They compile to:

```
public void f();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   dup
   2:   monitorenter
   3:   monitorexit
   4:   return

public synchronized void g();
  Code:
   0:   return
```

As you can see, `g()` is still marked as `synchronized` in the bytecodes, so the JVM knows what to do.

*Disclaimer:* This is what my compiler does. It seems possible that a different compiler might chose to emit `monitorenter`/`monitorexit` instead of using `ACC_SYNCHRONIZED`. Whether any existing compiler does that, I don't know.

Comment: So the `synchronized` in the method declaration is translated differently?I was expecting to see `monitorenter` in `g()` as well

Answer (score 0):

> synchronized keyword does not create monitor

The mutex or monitor is the object itself.
In Java the `synchronized` keyword is `implicit` locking i.e. it uses the objects iternal lock for sunchronization