# Why synchronized in static method and in Class get different java byte code

Tags: java

I have learned that synchronized in static method and Class are the same thing, they are both class level lock.

Then I try to write a demo program:

```java
package com.hao.thread;

public class Main {
    private static int count = 10;

    public synchronized static void m1() {
        --count;
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " count = " + count);
    }

    public static void m2() {
        synchronized (Main.class) {
            --count;
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " count = " + count);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

After compile, and check the java bytecode with jclasslib(a idea plugin), I found `m1()` and `m2()` got different java bytecode, there is no `monitorenter` in the bytecode of `m1()` method.

the pictures are follows, because I don't have enough reputation, I have to paste the direct link of image

- `m1()` java bytecode: `![m1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRzJ5.jpg)`
- `m2()` java bytecode: `![m2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrTvJ.jpg)`

I wonder why it happen? And with the different java bytecode, how can they have the same behaviour? Is there any extra thing JVM done for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [JVM Specification §17.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html) - the VM sees the 'synchronized' keyword and does the `monitorenter` implicitly. There are 2 ways to obtain the lock on an object in java bytecode: Either via a `synchronized` keyword, or via a `MONITORENTER` bytecode, it's as simple as that.

Comment: No, and your reference does not say this. There are no keywords present at runtime. The Java compiler sees the `synchronized` keyword and sets the `ACC_SYNCHRONIZED` flag on the method access flags in the `method_info` bytecode. It is this flag which is seen by the JVM.

Comment: That's nitpicking. 'the synchronized keyword', in the context of class files / JVMS (vs the JLS) is obviously referring to ACC_SYNCHRONIZED. Let's not be too condescending to the question asker :)

Comment: I got it, after reading [JVM Specification §17.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html) and another two links [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52892370/same-bytecode-for-method-with-or-without-synchronized-keyword-in-method-signatur), [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117115/why-synchronized-keyword-does-not-create-monitor-enter-every-time), and then I check the `m1()` method's bytecode, there did be a synchronized access_flag of `m1()`, thanks a lot.